# C++ refactoring (renaming) tools for open source projects

Tags: cross-platform, c++, refactoring

The tool should be able to perform simple tasks like renaming a class or function. It should be usable by cross-platform open source projects, so that rules out anything Visual Studio based. However, proprietary software that is free to use by open source projects is okay, as long as there's a release for all the important platforms(windows, GNU/linux, mac OS X).

The tool should ensure that the refactoring is semantically correct, i.e. it shouldn't just do a plaintext find/replace.

The clang project is working on [an API](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) suited for the creation of such tools,

[Related stackoverflow question, closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969109/any-c-c-refactoring-tool-based-on-libclang-even-simplest-toy-example)

Comment: Why not use Eclipse IDE?

Comment: And that tool should integrate in any C++ IDE? Maybe your expectations are a little bit too high...

Comment: You have tagged that [tag:open-source]. Are you looking for open source tools or are you also looking for commercial tools which can be used freely in open source projects (a model that JetBrains follows)?

Comment: I was not aware the eclipse IDE could do that, but then again I've not much dived into eclipse CDT. If CDT can do such things, I think it's a perfectly valid answer to this question!

Comment: Commercial tools that can be freely used in open source projects are fine.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't see why--this would be entirely possible with a command-line tool using a [JSON file of the build commands for the project](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html) (yes, the only two tools that page mentions that are capable of generating such a file are CMake and Ninja, but the format is pretty simple, so I expect support to grow over time).

Comment: CLion currently only supports CMake projects, but it looks fairly promising. (I haven't tried it out yet, though.)

Answer (score 5):

The Eclipse CDT tool (http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) would seem to match your requirements.

It has rename facilities, and a number of other refactoring operations.

It is open source itself, so you can use it as you like on open (or closed source).

I doubt its refactoring is semantically correct in a narrow sense. C++ is an extremely complex language and changing it is difficult to do accurately under all circumstances (consider renaming of some templated class whose definition depends on a complex template instantiation).  That said, I think the CDT refactoring machinery is based on carefully constructed progam parsing, analysis and transformations implemented using compiler-like methods; it is not "a plaintext find/replace".

I have no personal experience with this tool.  However, I do build program transformation tools as a living, including those that transform C++ (but would not be a legitimate answer to the "available refactoring tool" or "free to use on open source" requirements). Having a keen interest in the technology behind such tools, I have personally visited and talked to the people that work on the refactoring aspects of the CDT  ([Peter Sommerlad's](http://wiki.hsr.ch/PeterSommerlad/wiki.cgi?PeterSommerlad) team), and have great respect for their skills in building such tools.